# 500 -server error in Laravel Framework 7.18.0 (doesn`t view any any error information on browser.)

Tags: php, laravel

``

[I copy and pasted this project file from another machine. The project works well on the previous machine. But now this error occurred. But other travel projects run without conflict on the new machine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crFpj.png)

Comment: Anytime you got 500 error, or run app in local, set APP_DEBUG=true in your .env file. You will get error detail

Comment: It is done but the problem is the same.

Comment: Yeah, but can show details? restart your laravel server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first composer install
check if server is running
check if the db name is same as the env db name
run php artisan key:generate
then php artisan migrate
then php artisan db:seed
now your project should be working